# Subtract one column by itself based on a condition set by another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following data frame, where `time_stamp` is already sorted in the ascending order:

```
    time_stamp          indicator
0   2021-01-01 00:00:00 1
1   2021-01-01 00:02:00 1
2   2021-01-01 00:03:00 NaN
3   2021-01-01 00:04:00 NaN
4   2021-01-01 00:09:00 NaN
5   2021-01-01 00:14:00 NaN
6   2021-01-01 00:19:00 NaN
7   2021-01-01 00:24:00 NaN
8   2021-01-01 00:27:00 1
9   2021-01-01 00:29:00 NaN
10  2021-01-01 00:32:00 2
11  2021-01-01 00:34:00 NaN
12  2021-01-01 00:37:00 2
13  2021-01-01 00:38:00 NaN
14  2021-01-01 00:39:00 NaN
```

I want to create a new column in the above data frame, that shows the time difference between each row's `time_stamp` value and the first `time_stamp` value above that row where `indicator` is not `NaN` (immediately above row, where `indicator` is not `NaN`).

Below is how the output should look like (`time_diff` is a timedelta value, but I'll just show subtraction by indices to better illustrate. For example, ( 2 - 1 ) = `df['time_stamp'][2] - df['time_stamp'][1]` ):

```
    time_stamp          indicator   time_diff
0   2021-01-01 00:00:00 1           NaT # (or undefined)
1   2021-01-01 00:02:00 1           1 - 0
2   2021-01-01 00:03:00 NaN         2 - 1
3   2021-01-01 00:04:00 NaN         3 - 1
4   2021-01-01 00:09:00 NaN         4 - 1
5   2021-01-01 00:14:00 NaN         5 - 1
6   2021-01-01 00:19:00 NaN         6 - 1
7   2021-01-01 00:24:00 NaN         7 - 1
8   2021-01-01 00:27:00 1           8 - 1
9   2021-01-01 00:29:00 NaN         9 - 8
10  2021-01-01 00:32:00 1           10 - 8
11  2021-01-01 00:34:00 NaN         11 - 10
12  2021-01-01 00:37:00 1           12 - 10
13  2021-01-01 00:38:00 NaN         13 - 12
14  2021-01-01 00:39:00 NaN         14 - 12
```

We can use a for loop that keeps track of the last `NaN` entry, but I'm looking for a solution that does not use a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up doing this:

```
# create an intermediate column to track the last timestamp corresponding to the non-NaN `indicator` value
df['tracking'] = np.nan 
df['tracking'][~df['indicator'].isna()] = df['time_stamp'][~df['indicator'].isna()]
df['tracking'] = df['tracking'].ffill()

# use that to subtract the value from the `time_stamp`
df['time_diff'] = df['time_stamp'] - df['tracking']
```